# A Question relating to a Turing Machine with a useless state

Tags: computability, undecidability, formal-methods, turing-machines

OK, so here is a question from a past test in my Theory of Computation class:

> A useless state in a TM is one that is never entered on any input string.  Let $$\mathrm{USELESS}_{\mathrm{TM}} = \{\langle M, q \rangle \mid  q \text{ is a useless state in }M\}.$$
>   Prove that $\mathrm{USELESS}_{\mathrm{TM}}$ is undecidable.

I think I have an answer, but I'm not sure if it is correct.   Will include it in the answer section.

Comment: In the future, please include your attempts in the question!

Comment: @Rapael Just did.  I wrote it up when I did the question, but given my lack of reputation I was unable to post it for at least 8 hours.  I'd be interested in knowing if it is a valid answer.

Comment: No, I meant just include it in the question if there are specific points where you are uncertain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is clearly reducible from the Halting Problem. If a machine $M$ does not stop on input $x$ then any final state is "useless". Given an input $M,x$ for the Halting problem, it is easy to construct $M_x$ that halts on every input (thus its final state is not useless) if and only if $M$ halts on $x$. That way you can decide Halting Problem if you can decide $\mathrm{USELESS}_{\mathrm{TM}}$, which yields a contradiction.

Comment: ..and since the Halting problem is undecidable, this problem is undecidable as well, correct?

Comment: Indeed, this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of this proof we will assume that $\mathrm{USELESS}_{\mathrm{TM}}$ is decidable to display a contradiction.

Create TM $R$ that does the following:

- Converts  TM $M$ to a pushdown automata $P$ with a relaxed stack (ie. no LIFO requirement).  This is equivalent to a directed graph detailing the transition between $M$'s states.
- Mark the start state of $P$.
- From the start state commence a breadth-first search along each outbound edge marking each unmarked node.
- When the search terminates, if there are any unmarked nodes which match $q$, *accept*; otherwise *reject*.

Then create TM $S$ = "On input $$

1. Create TM $R$ as shown above.
2. Run $q$ on $R$.
3. If $R$ returns accept, *accept*; if $R$ rejects, *reject*"

Thus, if $R$ is a decider for $\mathrm{USELESS}_{\mathrm{TM}}$ then $S$ is a decider for $A_{\mathrm{TM}}$ (the acceptance problem).  Since $A_{\mathrm{TM}}$ is proven to be undecidable (see Michael Sipser *Theory of Computation* Theorem 4.11 on page 174), we have reached a contradiction.  Therefore, the original hypothesis is incorrect and $\mathrm{USELESS}_{\mathrm{TM}}$ is undecidable.

Comment: What is the meaning of turning a TM into a PDA with a relaxed stack?

Comment: Is $R$ the decider assumed to exist? if so - you don't need to describe its action. In fact you  **can't** describe its action, since it doesn't really exists. All you know that it answers yes/no according to whether or not the input is in $L$.